# Как сделать форму ввода данных (email и число- идентификатор) с помощью Java JSF?

Tags: sqlite, jsf, webforms

Как сделать форму ввода данных (email и число- идентификатор) с помощью Java JSF? Или лучше для этого PrimeFaces или другая библиотека?
Нужно сохранять результаты ввода данных пользователем в один Excel или SQLIte БД.

Comment: вы имеет опыт работы с JSF?

Comment: мало, знаю Drupal, Android, Java FX, Python, ASP MVC, иначе бы не спрашивал

Comment: а можете описать задачу, а не решение?